# Got an error while sending email via sendmailR

Tags: r, sendmailr

I have a table that I am trying to get to clients via `sendmailR`. I would like to stick to `sendmailR` as well. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
from <- 'my email'
to <- 'my email'
subject <- paste("the subject",Sys.Date(),sep=" ")
sendmail(from, to, subject, str, control = list(smtpServer="the correct server sits here"))
```

Sorry for all the censoring. Just know that this same exact code used to work about 4 months ago when I originally built the script it's in. Now to the error.

Here's what I am getting :

> Error in wait_for(code) : SMTP Error: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably that you are sending through a blocked port. The default port for `sendmail` is 25. If you are at a place where you don't control the servers, try asking a tech guy what server you need to set it as. Here's the command to do so. Add it before the `sendmail()` command

`sendmail_options(smtpPort="25")`

Change 25 to whatever port your tech guy tells you to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mailR (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mailR/index.html) that supports SMTP authentication.